# Piece class as part of implementation for the Tetris game

Tags: java, array, unit-testing, junit, tetris

Here is my `Piece` class as part of implementation for the Tetris game. If possible, I want my code to face the same level of scrutiny as actual production code.

Hereare some of the potential areas in which I feel my code could be improved, but due to my limited experience, was unable to do so. Please help me provide suggestions on, but not limited, to these areas.

1. I want to make "Piece next" variable "final",  but don't know how it can be initialised in the constructor
2. I expect `testGetNextPiece2` and `testGetNextPiece3` in "PieceTest.java"
   to pass, but both test methods failed, but I can't find anything wrong with my `Piece` class code nor the test methods.
3. Testing edge cases I have missed (I have focused solely on the "pyramid" piece, because I don't want to cluster this page with similar tests on different pieces).

Here is the link to the [assignment requirements](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs108/handouts152/15HW2Tetris.pdf) of which I also attached some screenshots below.

**Requirements**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**class Piece**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


class Piece {

    /**
     * array of "TPoints" that make up the current instance of "Piece",
     */
    private final TPoint[] body;
    /**
     * skirt is an int[] array with as many elements as the piece is wide,
     * the skirt stores the lowest y value that appears in the body for each x value in the piece,
     * the x values are the index into the array
     */
    private final int[] skirt;
    /**
     * the width of piece after been placed on the lower left hand of the board
     */
    private final int width;

    /**
     * the height of piece after been placed on the lower left hand of the board
     */
    private final int height;
    /**
     * the resulting piece after rotating the current piece in counter clock direction
     */
    private Piece next; 

    /**
     * array that represent all possible pieces
     */
    private static final Piece[] pieces;

    static {
        pieces = Piece.getPieces();
    }

    /**
     * construct a new piece object from a existing array of TPoint, 
     * @param points - array of TPoint that together make up the body of a Piece object
     */
    Piece(TPoint[] points) {

        body = new TPoint[points.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            body[i] = new TPoint(points[i]);
        }

        //calculate "width" and "height" of the piece using the "body" 
        int xMax = 0;
        int yMax = 0;
        for (TPoint point : body) {
            if (xMax < point.x) {
                xMax = point.x;
            }
            if (yMax < point.y) {
                yMax = point.y;
            }
        }

        //because coordinate of board starts from (x, y) = (0, 0) from the lower left corner,
        //therefore in order to calculate actual "width" and "height" of the piece,
        //have to add 1 to the x coordinate of the piece at the far right to get the width,
        //and add 1 to the y coordinate of the piece at the top to get the height
        width = xMax + 1;
        height = yMax + 1;

        skirt = calculateSkirt();
    }

    /**
     * convenient initializer, initialize a new Piece from a existing piece
     * @param piece 
     */
    Piece(Piece piece) {
        this(piece.body);
    }

    /**
     * convenient initializer, initialize a new Piece from a string that represent 
     * x and y coordinate of TPoints that make up the body of a piece 
     * @param points a string that contain x and y coordinates of TPoints in pair, 
     * e.g. "0 0   0 1" represents two TPoints at coordinate (0, 0) and (0, 1)          
     */
    Piece(String points) {
        this(parsePoints(points));
    }

    /**
     * public getter for the next piece after rotation 
     * @return the resulting piece after the current piece rotate 90 degrees in counter clock direction 
     */
    public Piece getNextPiece() {
        return next;
    }

    public int[] getSkirt() {
        return skirt;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * goes through each TPoint that make up the current piece, 
     * for a given x coordinate,
     * find the piece located on this x coordinate that has the lowest y coordinate.
     * 
     * x coordinate of each TPoint can be thought of as index number in "int[] skirt"
     * @return an array that contain the lowest y coordinate in each x coordinate 
     */
    private int[] calculateSkirt() {

        int[] pieceSkirt = new int[width];
        Arrays.fill(pieceSkirt, height - 1);
        for (TPoint point : body) {
            if (point.y < pieceSkirt[point.x]) {
                pieceSkirt[point.x] = point.y;
            }
        }
        return pieceSkirt;
    }

    // String constants for the standard 7 tetris pieces
    static final String STICK_STRING = "0 0 0 1  0 2  0 3";
    static final String L1_STRING = "0 0    0 1  0 2  1 0";
    static final String L2_STRING = "0 0    1 0 1 1  1 2";
    static final String S1_STRING = "0 0    1 0  1 1  2 1";
    static final String S2_STRING = "0 1    1 1  1 0  2 0";
    static final String SQUARE_STRING = "0 0  0 1  1 0  1 1";
    static final String PYRAMID_STRING = "0 0  1 0  1 1  2 0";

    // Indexes for the standard 7 pieces in the pieces array
    static final int STICK = 0;
    static final int L1 = 1;
    static final int L2 = 2;
    static final int S1 = 3;
    static final int S2 = 4;
    static final int SQUARE = 5;
    static final int PYRAMID = 6;

    /**
     * calculate all possible pieces in all possible orientation
     * @return array of all possible pieces in its original position, 
     *      each piece contain a variable "next", which is a pointer to the piece 
     *      after the current piece rotate 90 degrees in counter clock direction 
     */
    static Piece[] getPieces() {
        //lazy evaluation -- create static array when needed
        if (Piece.pieces == null) {
            Piece[] piecesCreated = new Piece[]{
                makeFastRotation(new Piece(STICK_STRING)),
                makeFastRotation(new Piece(L1_STRING)),
                makeFastRotation(new Piece(L2_STRING)),
                makeFastRotation(new Piece(S1_STRING)),
                makeFastRotation(new Piece(S2_STRING)),
                makeFastRotation(new Piece(SQUARE_STRING)),
                makeFastRotation(new Piece(PYRAMID_STRING))
            };
            return piecesCreated;
        } else {
            return Piece.pieces;
        }
    }

    /**
     * calculate all possible position of a piece
     * @param passedInPiece the piece in its original position
     * @return the passed in original piece, but now this piece has a variable "next",
     * that is initialized and is pointing to the piece after rotation was completed,
     * this forms a circle of points (i.e. variable "next") which eventually points back to the original piece.
     */
    private static Piece makeFastRotation(Piece passedInPiece) {
        Piece currentPiece = new Piece(passedInPiece);

        Piece myRootPiece = currentPiece;

        while (true) {
            Piece nextRotation = currentPiece.computeNextRotation();
            if (nextRotation.equals(myRootPiece)) {
                currentPiece.next = myRootPiece;
                break;
            }
            currentPiece.next = nextRotation;
            currentPiece = currentPiece.next;
        }

        return myRootPiece;
    }

    /**
     * calculate the position of next piece after the current piece rotate 90 degrees 
     * in counter clock direction
     * @return the position of next piece after rotation 
     */
    Piece computeNextRotation() {
        TPoint[] rotatedBody = new TPoint[body.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
            rotatedBody[i] = new TPoint(height - 1 - body[i].y, body[i].x);
        }

        Piece computedNext = new Piece(rotatedBody);
        return computedNext;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //standard equals() technique 1
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        //standard equals() technique 2
        if (!(obj instanceof Piece)) {
            return false;
        }

        Piece other = (Piece) obj;

        if (other.body.length != body.length) {
            return false;
        }

        List<TPoint> myPoints = Arrays.asList(body);
        List<TPoint> otherPoints = Arrays.asList(other.body);

        return myPoints.containsAll(otherPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 37 * hash + Arrays.deepHashCode(this.body);
        hash = 37 * hash + Arrays.hashCode(this.skirt);
        hash = 37 * hash + this.width;
        hash = 37 * hash + this.height;
        hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.next);
        return hash;
    }

    /**
     * convert a string that represents the x and y coordinate of an array of TPoints 
     * to an actual array of TPoints
     * @param string a string that represents the x and y coordinate of an array of TPoints
     * @return array of TPoints that represents the body location of a piece 
     */
    private static TPoint[] parsePoints(String string) {
        List<TPoint> points = new ArrayList<TPoint>();
        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(string);
        try {
            while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());
                int y = Integer.parseInt(tok.nextToken());

                points.add(new TPoint(x, y));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not parse x,y string:" + string);
        }

        // Make an array out of the collection
        TPoint[] array = points.toArray(new TPoint[0]);
        return array;
    }

}
```

**Test class:**

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author justin
 */
public class PieceTest {

    private Piece pyramid1, pyramid2, pyramid3, pyramid4;
    private Piece square1, square2, square3;
    private Piece stick1, stick2, stick3;
    private Piece L21, L22, L24;
    private Piece s, sRotated;
    private Piece[] pieces;


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        pyramid1 = new Piece(Piece.PYRAMID_STRING);
        pyramid2 = pyramid1.computeNextRotation();
        pyramid3 = pyramid2.computeNextRotation();
        pyramid4 = pyramid3.computeNextRotation();

        square1 = new Piece(Piece.SQUARE_STRING);
        square2 = square1.computeNextRotation();
        square3 = square2.computeNextRotation();

        stick1 = new Piece(Piece.STICK_STRING);
        stick2 = stick1.computeNextRotation();
        stick3 = stick2.computeNextRotation();

        L21 = new Piece(Piece.L2_STRING);
        L22 = L21.computeNextRotation();
        L24 = L22.computeNextRotation().computeNextRotation();

        s = new Piece(Piece.S1_STRING);
        sRotated = s.computeNextRotation();

        pieces = Piece.getPieces();
    }

    /**
     * Test of getNextPiece method, of class Piece.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetNextPiece() {
        System.out.println("getNextPiece");
        assertTrue(pyramid1.equals(pieces[Piece.PYRAMID]));
        assertTrue(pyramid2.equals(pieces[Piece.PYRAMID].getNextPiece()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetNextPiece2(){
        System.out.println("getNextPiece2");
        assertTrue(pyramid2.equals(pyramid1.getNextPiece()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetNextPiece3(){
        System.out.println("getNextPiece3");
        assertEquals(pyramid2, pyramid1.getNextPiece());

    }

    /**
     * Test of getSkirt method, of class Piece.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetSkirt() {
        System.out.println("getSkirt");
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{0, 1}, pyramid4.getSkirt());
    }

    /**
     * Test of getHeight method, of class Piece.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetHeight() {
        System.out.println("getHeight");
        assertEquals(2, pyramid1.getHeight());
    }

    /**
     * Test of getWidth method, of class Piece.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetWidth() {
        System.out.println("getWidth");
        assertEquals(3, pyramid1.getWidth());
    }

    /**
     * Test of equals method, of class Piece.
     */
    @Test
    public void testEquals() {
        System.out.println("equals");
        boolean expResult = true;
        boolean result = pyramid1.equals(pyramid4.computeNextRotation());
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals2(){
        System.out.println("equals2");
        boolean expectedResult = true;
        Piece rootPiece = pieces[Piece.PYRAMID].getNextPiece().getNextPiece().getNextPiece().getNextPiece();
        boolean result = pyramid1.equals(rootPiece);
        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }

//    /**
//     * Test of hashCode method, of class Piece.
//     */
//    @Test
//    public void testHashCode() {
//        System.out.println("hashCode");
//        Piece instance = null;
//        int expResult = 0;
//        int result = instance.hashCode();
//        assertEquals(expResult, result);
//        // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to fail.
//        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
//    }

    /**
     * Test of getPieces method, of class Piece.
     */
    @Test
    public void testGetPieces() {
        System.out.println("getPieces");
        Piece[] expResult = new Piece[]{
            new Piece(Piece.STICK_STRING),
            new Piece(Piece.L1_STRING),
            new Piece(Piece.L2_STRING),
            new Piece(Piece.S1_STRING),
            new Piece(Piece.S2_STRING),
            new Piece(Piece.SQUARE_STRING),
            new Piece(Piece.PYRAMID_STRING)
        };
        Piece[] result = Piece.getPieces();
        assertArrayEquals(expResult, result);

    }

    /**
     * Test of computeNextRotation method, of class Piece.
     */
    @Test
    public void testComputeNextRotation() {
        System.out.println("computeNextRotation");
        TPoint[] points = new TPoint[]{
            new TPoint(0, 1),
            new TPoint(1, 0),
            new TPoint(1, 1),
            new TPoint(1, 2)
        };
        Piece expResult = new Piece(points);
        Piece result = pyramid1.computeNextRotation();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have written this game during Job selection process of one mobile game company. Hopefully I Will provide you something.

Comment: @GauravaAgarwal that would be wonderful. Any assistant would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Dejaveu, i wrote tetris when i was 17 in turbo pascal.

Comment: @PeterRader could you please have a look at my code? I'm a relatively newbie at programming, really want to improve my code quality. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some initial thoughts:

- Try to avoid numbered names. How is `pyramid1` different to `pyramid2`? What does `testGetNextPiece2` test that `testGetNextPiece` doesn't? The more descriptive your names are, the easier your code will to follow, change and debug.
- `getNextPiece` returns the piece after it has been rotated counter clockwise.  Why not call it `getPieceRotatedCounterClockwise`? It's more descriptive and you wouldn't need the comment to explain what it is...
- `myPoints.containsAll(otherPoints)` what happens if `myPoints` contains all of `otherPoints` but `otherPoints` doesn't contain all of `myPoints`?
- Don't leave commented out code. If you don't need it, delete it (use source control if you are worried about losing something).  Leaving the comment there just creates noise.  If a test isn't ready, then `@Ignore` ideally with a reason message to explain why it's disabled.